# Not installing pip on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, pip

Tried -

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

giving error -

```
E: Package 'python3-setuptools' has no installation candidate
```

Tried -

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

giving error -

```
E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

When checked for universal repository -

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

For any other command too, giving error as python3-packagename has no installation candidate.

I checked the version of python, it is 3.8.2 . I installed 3.9 now and how to make it default. I want to try it so that whether it may works.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254309/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Try this question on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394543/pip-install-problem-with-ubuntu-18-04-and-python-3-6-5 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422929/e-unable-to-locate-package-python-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296498/unable-to-install-pip-in-ubuntu/44296569

Answer (score 13):

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add these lines.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit nano.

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

This works.
I also works with

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Comment: You should generally refrain from using other release's repositories. This may sometimes lead to dependency issues with other packages and may make your system to receive updates that are originally intended for bionic. The packages you mentioned are there in focal as well. Consider restoring Focal's repositories and try again. `python3-pip` is In Universe and `python3-setuptools` is in main. If still you can't get those packages, consider editing question and adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `apt-cache policy python3-pip python3-setuptools`.

Comment: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install python3-pip` is enough

Comment: The below preceding example is working  
`sudo apt update`  and 
`sudo apt install python3-pip`
 Thanks a Ton `@Kulfy`